# What is the difference between:

Tags: c, syntax, malloc

```
struct ArrayQueue *Q = (struct ArrayQueue*)malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayQueue));
```

vs

```
struct ArrayQueue *Q = malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayQueue));
```

I am bit confused as to what to use when and exactly what difference do they bear? Intuitively, I feel the first usage is when I'm writing within a function and the second would be when I'm writing within a structure.

Comment: Are you writing in C?

Comment: Yes I'm writing in C.

Comment: Both usages have been used by Narsimha Karumanchi in his book...

Comment: They work the same. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: I like the second usage (everywhere) because it requires less typing, and there's no need for the cast. You can't write those statements inside a structure anyway, so I'm not sure what you mean in your latest edit.

Comment: Writing the code from the book as it is:

struct ArrayQueue *Queue(int size){
struct ArrayQueue *Q = malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayQueue));
}

The link you provided helped, though! :)

Comment: OK, what you just typed is a function named Queue that returns a pointer to an ArrayQueue struct. It looks like you're declaring a structure at first, but you aren't. Inside the function, you declare a pointer to an ArrayQueue struct, name it Q, and set its value to the output of `malloc`. Anyway, none of this has an effect on whether you cast the output of `malloc`. I don't know why the author is being inconsistent, but you don't need to switch back and forth like that.

Comment: ok...Thanks a lot @yellowantphil!!

Answer (score 0):

By default the function malloc returns a void*. Although you do not have to explicitly cast to the type you want(the compiler will do that), there are programmers that like to make that clearer.

That`s up to your coding style, both are acceptable.